# python view not working after deploying django app

Tags: python, django-views, mod-wsgi

I am attempting to deploy a new app using apache and mod-wsgi. The app simply takes a date provided in the post request and plots a graph and a table for a specific time range.
The date appears to get set correctly using the python internal (development) web server, however it fails when using apache/wsgi. The issue appears to be with the view;

```
# Set initial date
custom_date = [1, 1, 2015]

def GetCustomData(request):
    global custom_date
    form = DateForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        custom_date[0] = (str(request.POST['custom_date_day']))
        custom_date[1] = (str(request.POST['custom_date_month']))
        custom_date[2] = (str(request.POST['custom_date_year']))
        date_reformat = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(custom_date[0]+' '+custom_date[1]+' '+custom_date[2]), '%d %m %Y')
        chart_date = date_reformat.strftime('%-d %b %Y')
        return render(request, 'custom_results.html', {'cdate': chart_date})

    else:
        date_reformat = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(custom_date[0]+' '+custom_date[1]+' '+custom_date[2]), '%d %m %Y')
        chart_date = date_reformat.strftime('%-d %b %Y')
        return render(request, 'custom_results.html', {'cdate': chart_date})
```

When using apache, the initial post request works fine, however when attempting to navigate to page 2 of the table, I get a "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" for the line following the "else" statement. I am assuming the way the Global data variable gets updated between apache and the development server is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must never use mutable global variables to store data like this. The variable will be the same for all users, which means one user will be able to change the display format for all subsequent users. Data like this should be stored in the session.

However, the cause of your problem is much simpler; the default data is composed of integers, but the stored data is strings. Generally you should use string interpolation rather than concatenating, but here you should probably store it as a single string anyway.

Also note that the last three lines of the if block are the same as the else block; you can simplify the view considerably.

```
def GetCustomData(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['custom_date'] = ' '.join(
            request.POST['custom_date_day'],
            request.POST['custom_date_month'],
            request.POST['custom_date_year']
        )
    custom_date = request.session.setdefault('custom_date', '1 1 2015')
    date_reformat = datetime.datetime.strptime(custom_date, '%d %m %Y')
    chart_date = date_reformat.strftime('%-d %b %Y')
    return render(request, 'custom_results.html', {'cdate': chart_date})
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense. I am trying to test this now, but getting and error `Exception Value:  
join() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`. I will get back to you.